# Combination of synch and asynch method call and based on the result from the asynch we need to loop the synch method call

Tags: node.js, protractor, node-oracledb

I've a use to implement in protractor jasmine suite where the first method call is generating random number which is synchronous and immediately after that asynchronous method call for a node oracle db to verify whether that random number exists in the db table or not. If it is exists, we need to generate another random number then we need to verify with db call.Here from second call we need to use do while loop for the above use case until the db table doesn't contan the random number

I've to integrate this use case in protractor.
need help in writing the code

Comment: Can you update your question with all the necessary details to understand the problem completely like code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Girish, more detail is needed.

Also, though the chance for a collision is probably very low, why not just get the unique value from the database since you have to make the round trip at least once anyway?